# Why are the values I output not translated into the array

Tags: c++

I was coding a program [cpp.sh/9rey](http://cpp.sh/9rey)

And, although I get the output from the cout functions on line 41, the values just aren't reflected in the array tables at line 68  for the second one -> SuccessiveTestArrayInt[ i ][ 1 ], although its correct for SuccessiveTestArrayInt[ i ][ 0 ] .

Are the values reflected from the cout functions on line 41 being re-written again later on?

```
int leng = sizeof(ContainsInitialString)/sizeof(ContainsInitialString[0]);

for (int i = 0; i <= leng; i++)
{
    IterationCount=0;
    //if (ChecksRight(i) == 1)
    ChecksRight(i);
        if (SuccessiveCheck == 1)
    {
        cout << "Successive Done" << endl;
        SuccessiveTestArrayChar[RowCount] = { ContainsInitialString[i] };
        cout << "Letters in Success-Char - [" << SuccessiveTestArrayChar[RowCount] << "]" << endl;
        SuccessiveTestArrayInt[RowCount][0] = { IterationCount };
        SuccessiveTestArrayInt[RowCount][1] = { i }; //Position
        m++;
        cout << "Letters in Success-Int repetition, position - [" << SuccessiveTestArrayInt[RowCount][0] << "]["<< SuccessiveTestArrayInt[RowCount][1] << "]  - [ m = " << m << "]" << endl;
        RowCount++;
        i++;
        i = level;

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "not Successful" << endl;
        level++;
        i = level;
    }
}

cout << " ////////////////New part Begins here //////////////////" << endl;
int leng1 = sizeof(SuccessiveTestArrayChar)/sizeof(SuccessiveTestArrayChar[0]);
cout << "leng1 = " << leng1 <<endl; 

for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
{
    cout << "[" << SuccessiveTestArrayChar[i] << "]" << endl;
}

int leng2 = sizeof(SuccessiveTestArrayInt)/sizeof(SuccessiveTestArrayInt[0]);
cout << " ////////////////SuccessiveTestArrayInt //////////////////" << endl;
for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
{
    cout << "[" << SuccessiveTestArrayInt[i][0] << "]" <<"[" << SuccessiveTestArrayInt[i][1] << "]" << endl;
}

cout << " ////////////////New part Ends here //////////////////" << endl; 
void ChecksRight(int i)
{
if (ContainsInitialString[i] == ContainsInitialString[i + 1])
{
    level = i;
    cout << "ChecksRight Function; i =" << i << "\ti+1 = " << i+1 <<endl;
    cout << ContainsInitialString[i] << " == " << ContainsInitialString[i + 1] << endl;
    SuccessiveCheck = 1;
    IterationCount++;
    cout << "IterationCount" << IterationCount<<endl;
    ChecksRight(i + 1);
}
else
{
    level++;
}
}
```

Comment: What output are you getting from line 68?

Comment: Here's the full code. [http://cpp.sh/9rey](http://cpp.sh/9rey) . Its from there.

The array I get from there ->
     ////////////////SuccessiveTestArrayInt //////////////////
[2][3]
[3][0]
[0][2]
[2][3]
[3][3]
[3][28]
[28][19]
[19][0]
[0][0]
[0][0]
[0][0]

Whereas  
while outputting, I get  

    Letters in Success-Int repetition, position - [2][0]  - [ m = 1]
    Letters in Success-Int repetition, position - [3][3]  - [ m = 2]

Answer (score 1):

Your array declaration reads like this:

```
int SuccessiveTestArrayInt[50][1];
```

And in lines 39, 68 and 86, you are accessing it like this:

```
SuccessiveTestArrayInt[RowCount][1] = { i }; //Position line 39
cout << "[" << SuccessiveTestArrayInt[i][0] << "]" <<"[" << SuccessiveTestArrayInt[i][1] << "]" << endl; // line 68
SuccessiveTestArrayInt[i][1] = SortArrayPosition[d]; // line 86
```

In all the above cases, you are accessing your array out-of-bounds. Since the second dimension is only 1 while declaration, you can access it via 0 only. Anything greater is out-of-bounds.

Maybe you meant to declare it as:

```
int SuccessiveTestArrayInt[50][2]; // note the second dimension size
```